# Using Asp.Net Site in different Websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iframe

I am currently doing a configurator with 3D models, like as when you configure a car online (3D Modell changing in time). The whole thing becomes an Asp.Net Core application.
My question is:
How can I have this configurator displayed on other websites (not Asp.net sites) without a link. Is this possible by means of an iframe or what would be the best way here.
thank you for your help

Comment: you can create API in asp.net core and use it anywhere to get the configuration

Comment: Do you want to use your ASP.NET application on website using other technologies stacks? Right?

Comment: Its more like i have a backend in Asp.Net which render the models and give it back to the site. The rendering is dynamical on the configuration the user takes on the website. 
So i guess API Calls will be the best way. But my concern is if the internet connection form the user is bad it will load extrem slowly. But we will try it with api calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your configurator site URL is https://www.3d.com.

As we know, if we want to get info from site, we need the url and send httprequest, usually we use a browser to access.  So I think it's the best way to open your configurator site by iframe.

#### Suggestion

You can integrate relevant code about 3d configurator in one or more js files. In the page that needs to be referenced, only the js file needs to be introduced. That can be used for more projects.